# Android: A PendingIntent is a form of an Intent, then why isn't PendingIntent a subclass of Intent?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-intent, android-pendingintent

They say that

> Generally, when there exists an "is-a" relationship between two
>   entities, there is an inheritance relationship in terms of OOP.

For example

> "A mountain bike is a bicycle."

So `MountainBike` is a subclass of `Bicycle` as well, as a `MountainBike` inherits the properties of `Bicycle`, and has some of its own as well.

**Now, generally speaking a PendingIntent is an Intent, isn't it? So why is a PendingIntent a subclass of Intent?**

Reference: [Developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> generally speaking a PendingIntent is an Intent, isn't it?

A `PendingIntent` can be best thought of as a wrapper around an `Intent`, identifying an operation to be performed (start an activity, start a service, send a broadcast) and a security context under which that operation should be performed.

Hence, a "has-a" relationship model is a perfectly reasonable approach here.